# How to create notifications in flutter to push user to update app on playstore

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

I created an app with flutter and i pusliged it to ios.
I would like to know how notify users  every time i publish each version on appstore.
For exemple, for now the current version is 1.0.0,
How to inform my users that i published the version 1.0.1 and make them download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider rewriting your question because without details i only can give you directions.

First of, you can use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) package to get current app version 
Then you would compare version user has installed with the latest version (i would do this with some sort of a backend)

about notifications:

I assume you are talking about **push-notifications?** If that is the case I suggest you have a look at *Firebase Cloud Messaging*

As much as i would love to i simply cant say more with so little details you gave

Comment: Works fine. I used [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) without another dependency and it works