# How to upgrade my flutter app automatically

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to upgrade my flutter app automatically :

I have this code in my main.dart, I want to use upgrader package:
how can I to implement the upgrader package to advise the user that there is a new app version in the play store:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProviderOficinaVirtual(),
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: MaterialApp(
          //home: UpgradeAlert(),
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            '/notas_mesa_entrada_page': (BuildContext context) => MesaEntradaPage(),
            '/': (BuildContext context) => SideBarMenuPage3(),
            'reclamos': (BuildContext context) => ReclamosPage(),
            'pagosyfacturacion': (BuildContext context) => PagoyFacturacionPage2(),
            'cortesProgramados': (BuildContext context) => CortesProgramadosPage2(),
            'oficinasHabilitadas': (BuildContext context) => OficinasHabilitadasPage(),
            'cuadroTarifario': (BuildContext context) => const CuadroTarifarioPage(),
            'menu_page': (BuildContext context) => Menu2Page(),
            'titularidad_page': (BuildContext context) => CambioTitularidadPage(),
            
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create notifications in flutter to push user to update app on playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143211/how-to-create-notifications-in-flutter-to-push-user-to-update-app-on-playstore)

Comment: I try to use package info plus to get my flutter app version, but when i run the code line
String version = packageInfo.version;

it says 1.0.0, but in my pubspeck.yaml I have version: 13.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping all your values of `routes` with a `UpgradeAlert` widget from [`upgrader`](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SideBarMenuPage3(),
        '/notas_mesa_entrada_page': (context) => MesaEntradaPage(),
        'reclamos': (context) => ReclamosPage(),
        'pagosyfacturacion': (context) => PagoyFacturacionPage2(),
        'cortesProgramados': (context) => CortesProgramadosPage2(),
        'oficinasHabilitadas': (context) => OficinasHabilitadasPage(),
        'cuadroTarifario': (context) => const CuadroTarifarioPage(),
        'menu_page': (context) => Menu2Page(),
        'titularidad_page': (context) => CambioTitularidadPage(),
      }.map((name, builder) {
        return MapEntry(
          name,
          (context) => UpgradeAlert(child: builder(context)),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just to copy and run this code and it doesn't work, my app initialize normally and I don't have nothing in my console.

Comment: What would be "doesn't work"? The `upgrader` package shows an AlertDialog to your user whenever there is a newer version of your app in the Play Store or App Store, it doesn't write to the console.

Comment: I mean that, when I run the code the app doesn't show me any AlertDialog.

Comment: What's your app's current version (declared on *pubspec.yaml*) and your app's Play Store version?

Comment: i have this:
"version: 1.0.0+13.0.8" and the version in the plays store is "version: 1.0.0+13.0.9"

Comment: I think the problem may be that the version number (1.0.0) and the build number (13.0.9) are different things, and `upgrader` may be disregarding the build number when comparing. For debug purposes, could you try temporarily setting your *pubspec.yaml* version to 0.1.0 and rerun your app to see if the dialog appears?

Comment: I write 0.1.0, and it works, but when I write "version: 13.0.9" and i build the appbundle I the play store shows me that i have already use the version 1, that is reason because i write "version: 1.0.0+13.0.9" in the yaml, how can i resolve it?